# KSQL EXTRACTJSONFIELD space in key name

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I'm having a problem with spaces in names when using EXTRACTJSONFIELD in KSQL
For example:

```
SELECT EXTRACTJSONFIELD(payload, '$.Successful Login') FROM MYSTREAM;
```

--this always returns NULL

How should I handle spaces in key names?

I have tried:

```
EXTRACTJSONFIELD(payload, '$.Successful%Login')
EXTRACTJSONFIELD(payload, '$.Successful%20Login')
EXTRACTJSONFIELD(payload, '$.[Successful Login]')
EXTRACTJSONFIELD(payload, '$."Successful Login"')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr: Use `[\\"` `label` `\\"]` to reference the field**

Test data:

```
echo '{"id":1,"test":{"Successful Login":1}}' | kafkacat -b localhost:9092 -t test1
```

Declare stream in KSQL and check message:

```
ksql> create stream test1 (id bigint, test varchar) with (kafka_topic='test1', value_format='json');

 Message
----------------
 Stream created
----------------
ksql> select id, test from test1;
1 | {"Successful Login":1}
```

Un-escaped reference of column doesn't work:

```
ksql> select extractjsonfield(test,'$.Successful Login') from test1;
null
```

Escape column using `[\\"` (also observe not using dot-notation either):

```
ksql> select extractjsonfield(test,'$[\\"Successful Login\\"]') from test1;
1
```

*This solution is courtesy of [novikovantonio](https://github.com/novikovantonio) on [this issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/1238)*

Answer (score 2):

I just tried Robin's response using KSQL 6 (CLI v6.0.0, Server v6.0.0). For me it does not work using two backslashes. For me  it only works using one backslash or no backslash in the ksqldb cli like so:

```
ksql> select extractjsonfield(test,'$[\"Successful Login\"]') from test1;
```

or
ksql> select extractjsonfield(test,'$["Successful Login"]') from test1;

For me it only works without backslashes when starting the query from the confluent command center (version 6.0.0) as well as when handing the query to a headless ksqldb server (confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:6.0.0 image) using a query file.